# Network error with axios on the test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs

I create my react app with CRA wrote a test file `example.test.js`. This file contains:

```
import axios from 'axios';


axios.get('http://localhost:3000/coins')
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error.response);
});

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(3).toBe(3);
});
```

Run the test, I've got:

```
 PASS  src/Api/Coins.test.js
  ✓ adds 1 + 2 to equal 3 (3ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.945s, estimated 1s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

  console.log src/Api/Coins.test.js:9
    { Error: Network Error        at createError (/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
        at XMLHttpRequest.handleError [as onerror] (/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:87:14)
        at XMLHttpRequest.callback.(anonymous function) (/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:289:32)
        at invokeEventListeners (/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:219:27)
        at invokeInlineListeners (/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:166:7)
        at EventTargetImpl._dispatch (/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:122:7)
        at EventTargetImpl.dispatchEvent (/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:87:17)
        at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:61:35)
        at XMLHttpRequest.abort (/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:405:16)
        at Object.abort (/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:315:13)
        at RequestManager.close (/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Document-impl.js:146:21)
        at Window.close (/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:362:29)
        at JSDOMEnvironment.dispose (/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js:44:19)
        at Promise.resolve.then (/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/runTest.js:102:17)
      config:
       { adapter: [Function: xhrAdapter],
         transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
         transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
         timeout: 0,
         xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
         xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
         maxContentLength: -1,
         validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
         headers: { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*' },
         method: 'get',
         url: 'http://localhost:3000/coins',
         data: undefined },
      request:
       XMLHttpRequest {
         onabort: null,
         onerror: { [Function: handleError] [Symbol(inline event listener wrapper)]: [Function] },
         onload: null,
         onloadend: null,
         onloadstart: null,
         onprogress: null,
         ontimeout: [Function: handleTimeout],
         upload:
          XMLHttpRequestUpload {
            onabort: null,
            onerror: null,
            onload: null,
            onloadend: null,
            onloadstart: null,
            onprogress: null,
            ontimeout: null,
            _ownerDocument: [Document],
            [Symbol(impl)]: [EventTargetImpl] },
         onreadystatechange: { [Function: handleLoad] [Symbol(inline event listener wrapper)]: [Function] },
         [Symbol(impl)]:
          EventTargetImpl {
            _eventListeners: {},
            [Symbol(wrapper)]: [Circular],
            [Symbol(DOM SymbolTree)]: [SymbolTreeNode] },
         [Symbol(flag)]:
          { synchronous: false,
            withCredentials: false,
            mimeType: null,
            auth: null,
            method: 'GET',
            responseType: '',
            requestHeaders: [Object],
            referrer: 'http://localhost/',
            uri: 'http://localhost:3000/coins',
            timeout: 0,
            body: undefined,
            formData: false,
            preflight: false,
            requestManager: [RequestManager],
            pool: [Object],
            agentOptions: [Object],
            strictSSL: true,
            proxy: undefined,
            cookieJar: [CookieJar],
            encoding: 'UTF-8',
            origin: 'http://localhost',
            userAgent: 'Node.js (linux; U; rv:v10.0.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)' },
         [Symbol(properties)]:
          { beforeSend: false,
            send: false,
            timeoutStart: 0,
            timeoutId: 0,
            timeoutFn: null,
            client: null,
            responseHeaders: {},
            filteredResponseHeaders: [],
            responseBuffer: null,
            responseCache: null,
            responseTextCache: null,
            responseXMLCache: null,
            responseURL: '',
            readyState: 0,
            status: 0,
            statusText: '',
            error: '',
            uploadComplete: true,
            abortError: true,
            cookieJar: [CookieJar],
            requestBuffer: null,
            requestCache: null,
            origin: 'http://localhost' } },
      response: undefined }

    Done in 149.43s.
```

To be sure, that the API works, I did a request with curl:

```
~/Desktop/react-reason/cockpit$ curl http://localhost:3000/coins
[
  {
    "coinSymbol": "BTC",
    "amount": 8.8
  },
  {
    "coinSymbol": "ETH",
    "amount": 12.4
  },
  {
    "coinSymbol": "XRP",
    "amount": 3412.48
  },
  {
    "coinSymbol": "ETH",
    "amount": 0.004
  }
```

Why it does not bring any data, when the test runs?

Comment: Use `console.error(error)` to see the error message. Line 9 is inside reject handler :)

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: Your test doesn't wait for the request to be finished, and when doing this kind of tests you should consider mocking `axios` instead doing actual requests

Comment: You are making request outside of the test. So it is been aborted by test environment when all your tests are done.

Comment: So when I do the request inside the test? It does not work too?

Comment: @zero_coding Do you really need this request? Are you testing your API? Usually you just mock request related stuff to make your test as fast as possible and avoid various network related test fails.

Comment: How to mock a request?

Comment: Just google for it :)

Comment: @zero_coding try this https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter